# How can I change the color of UISearchBar "cancel" button in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am having trouble getting anything to work. I have a UISearchBar in my UIViewController. I just want to simply change the color of "Cancel" because the default blue does not really go well with my design. I would like it to also work on iOS 8. I found the following but it is not working for me:

```
(UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self])).tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

> Type UIBarButtonItem has no member appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses

I believe this is not even in swift 3 and I am having trouble trying to convert it...

Answer (score 1):

`appearance()` just returns `Self`, in this case a `UIBarButtonItem` instance.  Just use `tintColor`:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

Comment: It does change the Cancel color as wanted but it also changes all of the toolbar icons to green which is unwanted in my case. Is it possible to somehow only change the Cancel button to green (in UISearchBar)?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.green works in iOS9 and above but I need for iOS8 too =/